Scala 3, ADTs, combining elements in a collection
I'm new to Scala and trying to use Scala 3 enums as ADTs, and I have a collection I'm trying to "reduce" down in the following way:
enum Stats:
    case MaximumHealth(val x: Float)
    case HealthRegen(val x: Float)

def combineStats: Array[Stats] =
    val startWith = Array(Stats.MaximumHealth(20), Stats.MaximumHealth(10), Stats.HealthRegen(5))

    // how can I iterate/recurse over 'startWith' and "combine" multiple stats 
    // (such as MaximumHealth) entries into one?
    // (ie, producing endWith below)?

    val endWith = Array(Stats.MaximumHealth(30), Stats.HealthRegen(5))
    endWith

How can I do this?  GroupBy is often suggested but I don't know how to group by just the enum case without the values of the parameters making Stats.MaximumHealth(20) and Stats.MaximumHealth(10) different groups.

You could use the class name or even the class.

This seems like a case for groupMapReduce, but first, I would prepare some methods on your enum to make life easier:
enum Stats:
  // override is needed because of def x below
  case MaximumHealth(override val x: Float)
  case HealthRegen(override val x: Float)

  // the common getter for x
  def x: Float

  // combinator function for reducing
  def +(that: Stats): Stats = this match
    case MaximumHealth(x) => MaximumHealth(x + that.x)
    case HealthRegen(x)   => HealthRegen(x + that.x)

Now, we can do this:
def combineStats: Array[Stats] =
  val startWith = Array(Stats.MaximumHealth(20), Stats.MaximumHealth(10), Stats.HealthRegen(5))

  val reduced: Map[Int, Stats] =
    startWith.groupMapReduce(_.ordinal)(identity)(_ + _)

  val endWith = reduced.values.toArray
  endWith

Alternative solution
In above solution, I tried to keep your data structur as unchanged as possible. If I were to face that task, I would probably change it like this:
enum StatsType:
  case MaximumHealth, HealthRegen

case class Stats(statsType: StatsType, x: Float)

Then one could do it like this:
def combineStats(stats: List[Stats]): List[Stats] =
  val reduced: Map[StatsType, Float] =
    stats.groupMapReduce(_.statsType)(_.x)(_ + _)
  reduced.map{case (statsType, x) => Stats(statsType, x)}.toList

Additional hint
Not directly related to your question, but: if you want to keep your data structure as an enum as in your question, I'd consider making the x a member of the enum itself (as a simpler solution for a "common getter"):
enum Stats(val value: Float):
  case MaximumHealth(x: Float) extends Stats(x)
  case HealthRegen(x: Float) extends Stats(x)


This allows different stats types to be combined (MaximumHealth can be added to a HealthRegen, which may not make sense in this domain and thus should be prohibited). Is there a way to avoid that while keeping the answer generic?

If you're looking for a solution where combining MaximumHealth with HealthRegen won't compile: I do not think that is feasibly possible when using groupMapReduce because the reduce function has the signature (B, B) => B where B is the type of values of the resulting map (so here, B needs to be the common upper bound). What you could do: a) restrict access to the combinator function to avoid it being misused (e.g. define it locally right above the call to groupMapReduce or as anonymous function parameter) and/or b) return the unmodified this if that is of an unexpected type.

using scala 3, + could be defined as extensions methods on the specific classes. then, the grouping is creating lists of specific Stats types, so it would more be a matter of convincing the compiler that all of the elements in each list are of the same specific type and can be added together. maybe some kind of casting during the mapping operation?

Of course: if you split up groupMapReduce into groupBy and map, then you could do asInstanceOf (with a target-type depending on the key) on the values in the map-step before reducing them. But I don't see any significant advantages (at least not for the example at hand).

P.S.: if you really want to be typesafe about this without using asInstanceOf you could look into shapeless HMap (see https://www.scala-exercises.org/shapeless/HMap ) and use that as an accumulator for doing foldLeft, but: I'm not sure if there is a similar construct for Scala 3 Furthermore: it would require quite a lot of setup code for defining the type-relations and it would drastically increase the cognitive load required to understand the code. (I'm don't work as a scala dev anymore, but I'm sure at least 80% of my former colleagues would have hated me for such a solution.)

Here's an idea:

def combineStats(stats: Array[Stats]): Array[Stats] =
    // use `Option` to keep track of totals so we know if the input array
    // included a particular `Stats` type or not
    var maxes: Option[MaximumHealth] = None
    var regens: Option[HealthRegen] = None
    
    // loop over the input array
    stats foreach {
        // check the type of the current `Stats` element
        case m @ MaximumHealth(h) =>
            maxes match
                // combine stats if we've seen a previous instance of this stat type
                case Some(MaximumHealth(t)) => maxes = Some(MaximumHealth(t + h))
                // if we haven't seen this stat type before, initialize the Option
                case _ => maxes = Some(m)
        // same logic as above for other `Stats` types
        case h @ HealthRegen(r) =>
            regens match
                case Some(HealthRegen(t)) => regens = Some(HealthRegen(t + r))
                case _ => regens = Some(h)
    }
    
    // create the result list and only add the combined values for `Stats` types encountered in the input  
    var ret: List[Stats] = Nil
    regens foreach { r => ret = r :: ret }
    maxes foreach { m => ret = m :: ret }
    
    // convert to Array because that's what the function must return
    ret.toArray

It may look a tad more complicated than necessary, but I wanted to make sure the result array only included Stats types that were present in the original array, this can be simplified a bit if that's not necessary.
EDIT:
If order is not important, this can also look like:

def combineStats2(stats: Array[Stats]): Array[Stats] =
    // group stats by the specific `Stats` class
    val m = stats.groupBy { _.getClass }
    
    // reduce each group list. we know that all of the stats types will match, but the compiler doesn't so will complain that this may not be an exhaustive match
    m.values.map { s => s.reduce {
        case (MaximumHealth(h1), MaximumHealth(h2)) => MaximumHealth(h1 + h2)
        case (HealthRegen(r1), HealthRegen(r2)) => HealthRegen(r1 + r2)
    }}.toArray

Would love to know if there's a way to tell the compiler that the above match is actually exhaustive

This requires new work for each new case added to the enum while a generic approach is possible in this case which would handle new cases natively.

Hence the last comment ;) Do you mind showing an example of how that could work?
